# compare radio button value to a predetermined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to compare the selected radio button value to a predetermined value, then display text corresponding to either a match or not a match. This seems like it should be simple enough but it is displaying the "match" text regardless of whether the two values match or not.

Here's my code:

```
submit: function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if($("input:radio[name=answers]:checked").val() == triviaGame.correctSelection) {
            $("#result").text("Correct!");
        } else {$("#result").text("I'm sorry, you did not select the correct answer :(");}
    });
```

I've also tried:

```
submit: function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($("input:radio[name=answers]:checked").val() == triviaGame.questions[questionSelectNum].choices[triviaGame.questions[questionSelectNum].choices[0]]) {
        $("#result").text("Correct!");
     } else {$("#result").text("I'm sorry, you did not select the correct answer :(");}
});
```

And I've tried `===` and `==` as well as other syntax tweaks.

I checked to make sure I was setting the values of the radio buttons correctly in my `nextQuestion` method and my test worked so I don't think that's the problem. What puzzles me the most is that the if (true) code executes when it shouldn't instead of the else (false) code executing when it shouldn't, which I think would be a more likely bug.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    <button id = "nextQuestion">Next Question</button>
    <br></br> 
    <div id = "questionDisplay"></div>
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" id= "1" name="answers" value="defaultVal">
    <label id= "labelOne">Answer 1</label>
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" id= "2" name="answers" value="defaultVal">
    <label id= "labelTwo">Answer 2</label>
    <br></br> 
    <input type="radio" id= "3" name="answers" value="defaultVal">
    <label id= "labelThree">Answer 3</label>
    <br></br>
    <input type="radio" id= "4" name="answers" value="defaultVal">
    <label id= "labelFour">Answer 4</label>
    <br></br>
    <button id = "submit">Submit</button>
    <br></br>
    <div id= "result">Please select an answer above</div>
</div>
```

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/odogeJa/1/edit?html,css,js,output) a link to the full code at jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I got the wrong end of the stick at first, I think you just need to update this section:

```
 //sets the values of each radio button to the same value as each radio's corresponding answer 
   $("#1") .val(triviaGame.firstAnswer);
   $("#2") .val(triviaGame.firstAnswer);
   $("#3") .val(triviaGame.firstAnswer);
   $("#4") .val(triviaGame.firstAnswer);
```

With this:

```
 //sets the values of each radio button to the same value as each radio's corresponding answer 
   $("#1") .val(triviaGame.firstAnswer);
   $("#2") .val(triviaGame.secondAnswer);
   $("#3") .val(triviaGame.thirdAnswer);
   $("#4") .val(triviaGame.fourthAnswer);
```

http://jsbin.com/OKecora/1/edit

Comment: Roger that. Thanks again!